# Elastic Search Apply Filter To Aggregated data

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, aggregation

I have an index with user locations and I want to pick latest location for each user and then apply somewhat complex filter to latest locations. I managed to pickup latest locations using aggregation and sort however I cannot find a way to apply filter to it after.

Filter or post_filter do not produce expected results because they are applied to hits not to aggregated locations. I saw some comments about Bucket script aggregation but available examples are very simple.
Is there a way to do in Elastic Search? It is very easy script in SQL. Any help is appreciated!

Sample ES query to aggregate locations:

> ```
> GET locations/_search
> {
>   "query": {
>       "bool": {
>           "must": {
>               "match_all": {}
>           }
>       }
>   },
>   "aggs": {
>       "users": {
>           "terms": {
>               "field": "user_id"
>           },
>           "aggs": {
>               "userLocations": {
>                   "top_hits": {
>                       "sort": [{
>                           "created": {
>                               "order": "desc"
>                           }
>                       }],
>                       "size": 1
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Sample SQL query (oversimplified, not based on actual data):

```
SELECT subquery.* FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Created DESC) AS "RowNumber",  
        UserId,
        Latitute,
        Longitude,
        Active,
        OrganizationId
    FROM Locations
) subquery
WHERE subquery.RowNumber = 1 AND Latitude < 10 AND Longitude > 0 AND Active = 1 AND OrganizationId = 123
```

Sample mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "user_id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "location_source_type": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "created": {
                "type": "date"
            }
            "active": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "org_id": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample data:

user_id location location_source_type created active org_id

1 (0,0) 1 2020-01-01 1 123

1 (0,0) 1 2020-02-01 1 123

1 (9,9) 1 2020-03-01 1 123

2 (8,8) 1 2020-04-01 1 123

Expected result:

1 (9,9) 1 2020-03-01 1 123

2 (8,8) 1 2020-04-01 1 123

This is example of filter I want to apply to aggregated data:

```
"post_filter": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            { "term": { "location_source_type": 1 }},
                            { "term" : { "org_id" : "123" }}
                        },
                        {
                            "range": { "created": { "lte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00" } }
                        }
                    ],
                    "filter": [{
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "1000km",
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 9,
                                "lon": 9
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: what filter do you want to apply? Can you please share your index mapping, sample data, and expected search result?

Comment: Can you share the SQL query you have in mind?

Comment: @Bhavya I updated description to answer your questions. Thank you!

Comment: @Val I updated description to answer your questions. Thank you!